# What is the purpose of Thread.sleep(ms,ns) in JDK?

Tags: java

Below is the source code of `Thread.sleep(long millis, int nanos)`. It does not sleep `nanos` at all. It just invokes `sleep(millis)`. Why JDK introduces such a misleading method?

```
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos)
throws InterruptedException {
    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
    }

    if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && millis == 0)) {
        millis++;
    }

    sleep(millis);
}
```

Comment: Probably because actual nanosecond timing is not available on most (any?) hardware platform.

Comment: And also because trying to achieve sub-millisecond resolution on sleep is pointless on a non-RT platform.